# Will google bot read the data which are fetched via jquery event -doucument.ready

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, callback, seo

We have an online book store which is powered by asp.net. The front page is little bit more resource demanding as featured books from many category are shown.

We are using 3 listview for showing books for 3 choosen categories. There is no problem except there is little bit lagging while page loads.

increasing the number of list view greater than 6 result in a large lag time.

I have the options of using call back so that data is fetched after the page has loaded.
since i am new to callback and jquery searching the net i came accross many beautiful carausel that will be a eye catching for users.

I have implemented them but before going live I want to know , will there will be any negative effect of this on our page ranking?

Comment: If you turn of JavaScript and visit your site, is it still usable?

Comment: no all link button and buttons stopped working, but rarely any one turn it off. Actually i am not concerned about user i am concerned about Google.

Comment: Point was that crawlers have no javascript.

Comment: @Travis I saw one answer @ http://mashable.com/2010/06/25/google-javascript/   I want to know does any body have tried on live servers??

Comment: Also I cant invest for a new domain as it will take time and money both, Just want to know has somebody tried knowingly/unknowingly ..please share your experience.

Answer (score 0):

**If you're in doubt about Javascript and SEO, do in pure HTML fist and, if really need, improve after with Javascript**.

- If your page is slow, work to make it fast.
- If is too much content that have to be loaded and you have to choose, try to priorize your HTML and your CSS, and after do the rest.
- If you really want to improve user experience with AJAX UIs, at least make a way that your site work without javascript, and if same interface is acessible via some page created via Javascript, use metatag canonical to say plain HTML page, so even if Google read your page will not be duplicated content.

The above tips are more guaranteed than risk making an interface that depends of Javascript. If you want to do something different that you have to stop and test before put into production.

---

Edit:

If you really want, exist a way to make websites that rely heavily on AJAX still work in [Making AJAX Applications Crawlable](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/)